# Convert Any Sting To A Specific Format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a type of string into camel case. Here's the string:

```
here %it -RAINS
```

**Expected Output**:

```
hereItRains
```

I tried the following:

```cs
public static string ToCamelCase(this string str)
{
    var words = str.Split(new[] { "_", "-", "%" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    words = words.Select(word => char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1)).ToArray();
    
    return string.Join(string.Empty, words);
}
```

Got the output as below:

```
Here It RAINS
```

Is there anything that I missed here? Here's the link that I tried so far - [CamelCase](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1F2zba)

Comment: `word.Substring(1)` should be `word.Substring(1).ToLower().Trim()` and add `" "` to your `Split` seps.

Comment: That worked @Dai. The only thing is the spacing. Any idea on that?

Comment: Your string split must also include space (" ") to take it out

Comment: You are only splitting on `_`, `-` and `%`. So the first entry of `words` will be `here ` (ending in a space). You should trim the words as you process them.

Comment: This actually worked. I've just one requirement that I am unable to deliver at present. If I've a pattern say, `a b c %d`, then the output should be `aBCD`. But I am getting `ABCD`. Any suggestion on this @CompuChip?

Comment: You can add `words[0] = words[0].ToLower();` ?  (NOTE: The example in your question will, with this change, return `hereItRains` )

Comment: Didn't work @Luuk.

Comment: @user8512043; You will have to add it in the correct place, which is left open as an exercise to you .... 

Comment: see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8HvaWn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `ToCamelCase` function as follows:

```
public string ToCamelCase(string str)
{
    var allWords = str.Split(new[] { "_", "-", "%", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();                      
    var words = allWords.Skip(1).Select(word => char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1).ToLower()).ToList();
    words.Insert(0, allWords[0]);
    return string.Join(string.Empty, words);
}
```

1. add `" "` to your Split collection.
2. add `.ToLower()` to word.Substring(1)
3. skip the first word with `allWords.Skip(1)`

**result:**

```
a b c %d ==> aBCD
here %it -RAINS ==> hereItRains
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have many answers here, but I would like to add a new one, which is using raw C# code to process the string, avoid some memory allocation and reduce processing time.

```
public static string ToCamelCase(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return value;

    var upperCase = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i]) || char.IsPunctuation(value[i]))
        {
            upperCase = true;
            continue;
        }

        char ch;

        if (upperCase)
        {
            ch = char.ToUpperInvariant(value[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            ch = char.IsLower(value[i]) ? value[i] : char.ToLowerInvariant(value[i]);
        }

        upperCase = false;

        sb.Append(ch);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

When we use methods like ToArray, Split, ToLower, Regex, etc, we are creating many objects in memory and this can be avoided with some logic.

##### Benchmark tests

[image: Benchmark tests]

Comment: Could you share the tool that you used for benchmark tests @Pedro Paulo?

Comment: It's a NuGet package called BenchmarkDotNet. Documentation link: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *regular expressions* in order to match all the words which we should turn into lower case (the very first word) or title case (all the rest words):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static string ToCamelCase(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  return string.Concat(Regex
    .Matches(value, @"\p{L}+")
    .Select(match => match.Value.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Select((word, index) => index == 0
       ? word
       : CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word)));
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iUJlRy)

Remarks:

1. `\p{L}+` pattern stands for "one or more *Unicode* letters".
2. `ToTitleCase` turns any word into title case except all capital letters words (which are treated as acronyms and not changed), that's why I call `ToLower()` for any word.

Comment: Any reason to use `InvariantCulture` for `ToLower` but `CurrentCulture` for `ToTitleCase`? Seems inconsistent. E.g. on a turkish system this would give unexpected results for words starting with 'I' (capital letter I).

Comment: @Klaus Gütter: My bad, thank you! Definitely it should be the same (either Invariant or Current) culture for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following code for one of my college assignment and it worked perfectly fine. The `ToCamelCase` function takes an input text, breaks it into words using spaces, underscores, and hyphens as delimiters, and then transforms each word to title case (capitalising the initial letter) except the first. The `TextInfo` class handles correct case depending on current culture.

```
class Program
{
    static string ToCamelCase(string input)
    {
        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        string[] words = input.Split(new[] { ' ', '_', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (words.Length == 0)
            return input;

        string camelCase = words[0].ToLower();
        for (int i = 1; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            camelCase += textInfo.ToTitleCase(words[i].ToLower());
        }

        return camelCase;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "convert_this_string_to_camel_case";
        string camelCaseOutput = ToCamelCase(input);

        Console.WriteLine(camelCaseOutput);
    }
}
```